# Weighted distance in sklearn KNN

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm making a genetic algorithm to find weights in order to apply them to the euclidean distance in the sklearn KNN, trying to improve the classification rate and removing some characteristics in the dataset (I made this with changing the weight to 0). 
I'm using Python and the sklearn's KNN.
This is how I'm using it:

```
def w_dist(x, y, **kwargs):
   return sum(kwargs["weights"]*((x-y)*(x-y)))

KNN = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1,metric=w_dist,metric_params={"weights": w})
KNN.fit(X_train,Y_train)
neighbors=KNN.kneighbors(n_neighbors=1,return_distance=False)
Y_n=Y_train[neighbors]
tot=0
for (a,b)in zip(Y_train,Y_vecinos):
    if a==b:
        tot+=1

reduc_rate=X_train.shape[1]-np.count_nonzero(w)/tamaño
class_rate=tot/X_train.shape[0]
```

It's working really well, but it's very slow. I have been profiling my code and the slowest part is the evaluation of the distance.

I want to ask if there is some different way to tell KNN to use weights in the distance (I must use the euclidean distance, but I remove the square root).

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is indeed another way, and it's inbuilt into scikit-learn (so *should* be quicker). You can use the `wminkowski` metric with weights. Below is an example with random weights for the features in your training set.

```
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(metric='wminkowski', p=2, 
                           metric_params={'w': np.random.random(X_train.shape[1])})
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I was also looking at that but the problem is that I must use the euclidean metric (is a university project so I have to follow some rules).

Comment: If you look at the [KNeighborsClassifier docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html) then you can see by setting `p=2` in the Minkowski metric it's equivalent to Euclidean distance. I've updated my answer so it's how you would need it.

Comment: Guau the improvement is huge. Thanks mate!!

Comment: FYI, as of scikit-learn v1.3 `wminkowski` metric was removed and now existing `minkowski` accepts `w` parameter, like `wminkowski` did.