# Re-calculate similarity ranking/sorting without re-sorting

Tags: python, knn

I have some code which calculates the nearest neighbors amongst some vectors (`values`).

However, the values of these vectors are dependent on weights. Each column of the vectors has a different weight at every iteration.

Just for the sake of the example, at the code below I try to find everytime the nearest neighbor of the last vector (`vector[3]`).

That's a very simplified version of my code:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
knn = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=1)

values = [
    [2, 5, 1],
    [4, 2, 3],
    [1, 5, 2],
    [4, 5, 4]
]

weights = [
    [1, 3, 1],
    [0.5, 2, 1],
    [3, 1, 2]
]

# weights set No1
new_values = []
for line in values:
    new_values.append([a*b for a,b in zip(line,weights[0])])    
knn.fit(new_values)
print(knn.kneighbors(new_values[3]))

# weights set No2
new_values = []
for line in values:
    new_values.append([a*b for a,b in zip(line,weights[1])])         
knn.fit(new_values)
print(knn.kneighbors(new_values[3]))

# weights set No3
new_values = []
for line in values:
    new_values.append([a*b for a,b in zip(line,weights[2])])        
knn.fit(new_values)
print(knn.kneighbors(new_values[3]))
```

(Obviously I could have a for loop for the different weights sets but I just wanted to point the repetition of the matter)

My question is, is there any way that I can avoid using the KNN 3 times but just use it once at the beginning to do the initial similarity ranking/sorting and then just do some re-calculations?

In different words, is there any way to reduce the computation complexity of this code in terms of calling the KNN fewer times?

PS
I know that there are KNN implementations which are much faster than the ScikitLearn one but that's not really the point; the point is more on using KNN just once instead of N=3 times or something like that.

Comment: How many values do you have in the not simplified `values` and `weight` lists? For all we know, the creation of the weighted lists could be more costly that calling KNN. `weighted_values = np.multiply(values, weight)` before KNN would help, especially if you have thousands of items in your values and weights.

Comment: @Guimoute thank you for your comment. Actually at the non-simplified version I use the in-built weighted KNN version of SkLearn (along these lines https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50064632/weighted-distance-in-sklearn-knn), So again the focus is not so much on the matrix multiplication but more on calculating the similarities (which can be considered a form of sorting) without having the re-run the whole algorithm if the only thing changed were the weights, if this is much possible. But matrix (re-)calculation can be very costly as we know indeed. Looking forward to any more comments.

Answer (score 0):

assuming `calling the KNN fewer times` means the number of times the KNN is fit, yes it's possible. if `calling the KNN` means the number of times kneighbors is invoked, that might be difficult due to how relative distances aren't preserved under affine transformations.
This solution runs in O(wk log n) time compared to the original O(wn) time with w being the number of weights.

what you're doing is

1. taking the input points
2. scaling its dimensions (projecting the input points into a new coordinate space)
3. building a knn model from the scaled inputs
4. classifying the target based on the scaled input.

However, consider

1. taking the input points
2. building a knn model from the scaled inputs
3. inverse scaling the target point (projecting the target into the original coordinate space)
4. classifying the inverse scaled target based on the input

the result of this process would be that steps 1 and 2 could be reused for each target point. weights with value 0 will require special handling.

this would look would be something like:

```py
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
knn = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=1, algorithm="kd_tree")

values = [
    [2, 5, 1],
    [4, 2, 3],
    [1, 5, 2],
    [4, 5, 4]
]

weights = [
    [1, 3, 1],
    [0.5, 2, 1],
    [3, 1, 2]
]

targets = [
    [4, 15, 4], # values[3] * weights[0]
    [2.0, 10, 4], # values[3] * weights[1]
    [12, 5, 8] # values[3] * weights[2]
]

knn.fit(values)

# weights set No1
print(knn.kneighbors([[a/b for a, b in zip(targets[0], weights[0])]]))

# weights set No2
print(knn.kneighbors([[a/b for a, b in zip(targets[1], weights[1])]]))

# weights set No3
print(knn.kneighbors([[a/b for a, b in zip(targets[2], weights[2])]]))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is an interesting answer by the way. But out of curiosity, do you really calculate the neighbours of the scaled values in your code (because that's the point)? I feel you calculate 3 times the same thing (ie the non-scaled values neighbours).

Comment: Yes it'll calculate the nearest neighbors of the inverse scaled target points 3 times but the runtime of this is O(log(n)) as the nearest neighbors algorithm internally uses a kd tree to search for nearest neighbors. The runtime of the original algorithm is O(n) as it's forced to transform the input data into the new coordinate space - not sure if that answers the question but hopefully helps

Comment: Ok yeah but what is the point of calculating 3 times the same thing and when this is not even the thing in question. I want to calculate the scaled values for these 3 different weightings. :)

Comment: sorry not sure what you mean - it looks like I'm understanding the question incorrectly. what is the thing in question precisely and what are the scaled values?

Comment: Ok sorry may be my terminology (eg scaling) was not appropriate :). I mean I want to calculate the KNN for the 3 different weighted value sets. It seems you calculate the neighbours for different unweighted values. Also I do not understand why you use target[0], target[1] etc. You should be using the whole matrix if you check my post well.